# Why sudden Type error appears when i insert only strings in exec() function?

Tags: python, type-conversion

So, I'm using an exec() function in python, I inserted only strings in it but i still get 
`TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int) to str`

How do i fix this?

```
def function(e_mass,x):
  global pic
  e_string = ""
  for i in range(len(e_mass)):
    if e_mass[i] == "x":
      e_string += str(x)
    else:
      e_string += e_mass[i]
  return e_string



exec("if y == " + function(e_mass,x) + ":" + "\n" + "  pic += 1" + "\n" + "else:" + "\n" + "  pic += 0")

sins = ['x', ' ', '+', '-', '*', '/', '%', '\n', '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']


for i in range(0,len(e)):
    e_mass.append(e[i])
    if e[i] not in sins:
      print("it's wrong, pal")
      break
    if e[i] == 'x':
      isx = 1
      xs.append(i)
```

Comment: You need to show a sample of `e_mass`. If an element is an `int` you will get the error you show. Please update the question with the full traceback.

Comment: Check what you are returning from the function.  I don't think you are doing what you are think you are doing.  a quick fix would be to:  return str(e_string) from the function.

Comment: Also, why are you using exec?  you could just have the code there to execute?

Comment: @LhasaDad: I don't think that `e_string` can be anything apart from a string since it is set to `""` to start and only operator `+=` is used.

Comment: @LhasaDad I need to insert an equation, only way I now is via exec. e_mass is always printed out, so i know it contains strs for sure. I've tried exec without a function and it still showed me the error

Comment: The error means that `e_mass` has some number type elements. The error will occur in the `else` part, where you try to do `+=` with a numeric operand. If you use `str()` there as well, then it will be OK. In fact, in the `if` block, you don't need `str()`, as there you *know* the value is a string.

Comment: @multus Not quite sure what you mean by "insert an Equation"  is this part of a class assignment or something?

Comment: The error is *proof* that `e_mass` does *not* only consist of strings. But output can be misleading. Numbers output as strings...

Comment: @trincot as i said e_mass is printed out, there are no other types except for str, also I've tried my code without "function()" and still got the same error

Comment: And as I said, you are wrong, because the error says it found a number (`int`) in that list. Who do you think I am going to believe now? :)

Comment: You could save us all discussing here, by just providing the code and data to *reproduce* the error. end of discussion then.

Comment: @trincot would it be helpfull if I sent you my input and code?

Comment: No, it would be helpful if you trimmed down the code & data you have up to a *minimum* that is necessary to still reproduce the issue. Then include that  in your question.

Comment: @trincot ok, sorry for answering answered questions, my connection is bad

Comment: @LhasaDad it's a mathematical thingy. You input a function and get a "graph" of it

Comment: @quamrana e_mass is a splitted string you input. For example x will be turned into ['x']. In this case e_mass couldn't contain any numbers.

Comment: That's what you say, but you haven't updated the question to show this.

Comment: @quamrana i've just did it, I've added several strings. To answer further questions   e = str(input())

Comment: Nowhere in your post do you call `split()`.

Comment: @quamrana I'm sorry for misunderstanding! I didn't use split(), I've used the last piece of code to split the string into separate signs

Answer (score 0):

the problem turned out to be in exec code. i forgot to put " before 1 and 0 in code

Comment: when you get something like this again.  you could assign the item you are trying to exec() to a variable and then print that to see what is going to be exec'ed before passing it to exec()